# sending file using built in bluetooth application in android

Tags: android, mobile, bluetooth

I am sending file using following code in my android application :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
intent.setType("image/png");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file) );  
startActivity(intent);
```

But it shows me list like email , bluetooth , and many other. I dont want this list and should be sent directly  without user interaction to perticular paired device .

Is it possible in android ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Can you please share the full source code I am also stuck on this point. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, current API's will not allow you to bypass user confirmation, but you can do this programmatically using the Bluetooth API's after the pairing stage. Establish a RFCOMM and then use InputStream/OutputStream to receive/send files. A great place to start is looking at the BluetoothChat example by google.

Comment: Could you please point me to the documentation? (Which you mentioned about current APIs)…

Comment: I think [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html) could help. Anyway, thanks  :-)